# missing eigenvalue using prcomp or PCA function in r

Tags: r

I have matrix with 29*39 dimensions, I want to calculate PCA.

```
pca_test_data<-data_30days[1:29,1:39]
pca_30days_1<-PCA(pca_test_data,scale.unit=F,ncp=n, graph=F)
pca_30days_1$eig
```

I only get 28 eigenvalues, I think I should get 39 eigenvalues. if I use `prcomp()`, I still get 28 eigenvalues.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include an [mcve], which is a) the desired behavior, b) the *specific problem or error* you're seeing and c) the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce your error

Comment: I disagree - I think you'll get a max of 29.  Sounds like there's one more in the null space, so you only get 28.

Comment: covariance matrix should be matrix(39*29)*matrix(29*39)=matrix(39*39), the eigenvalue of (matrix(39*39)) should have 39 eigenvalues?